# 97 Suburban overheating

Tags: chevrolet, cooling-system, overheating, suburban

Lower radiator hose is hot upper radiator hose is cold and thermostat has been removed but it still overheats, water boils out when the radiator cap is removed.

It overheats while not moving, as well as moving, the heater works intermittently, but doesn't get very warm, and it does lose coolant, there were no obvious leaks until the outside temperature recently dropped well below freezing and now I notice a small amount of slushee ice under the front/middle of the engine. I picked up a new water pump yesterday, and am going to replace it today.

Comment: Is this a 1500 or 2500 Suburban? 350 V8? 4x4 or 2WD? Does it not boil over if the cap is in place?

Comment: Does it overheat while moving?  While not moving?  Does the heat work?  Is it leaking coolant anywhere?

Comment: It overheats while not moving, as well as moving, the heater works intermittently, but doesn't get very warm, and it does lose coolant, there were no obvious leaks until the outside temperature recently dropped well below freezing and now I notice a small amount of slushee ice under the front/middle of the engine. I picked up a new water pump yesterday, and am going to replace it today.

Comment: So what is you question?